# Find all of the least-squares solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$x + y = 2; x + y = 4$$

So I got it into matrix form $$A = [1, 1; 1, 1]; b = [2, 4].$$

Now do I just solve the equation $$(A^tA)\vec{x} = A^t\vec{b}$$

Hints only would be appreciated and I'd only like to know if I am spot on; I have a test tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Here's an informal justification of why this is correct:

Suppose $Ax = y$, we want the size of $y - b$ to be minimum. This will happen if $y$ is orthogonal to $y - b$, i.e. if $(Ax)^T(Ax - b) = 0$.

Now, if you expand the left hand side, you see that you want
$$
x^T(A^TAx - A^Tb) = 0
$$

which will hold if $A^TAx = A^Tb$.